# Proper way to store username and password in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, security, storage

What is the best way to store confidential data like usernames, passwords, etc in an iOS application?

Comment: it depends on kind of app you are creating. In banking apps it is not saved at all. Every time you feed user+pwd it goes to server and comes back with some valid tokens etc and let you to access your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides the keychain for storing sensitive information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897

You should not use NSUserDefaults or CoreData unless you have provided some means of encrypting the content, and even so, you'll still need to manage and store encryption keys securely.  The keychain provides all of this for you, and with iOS 8 you can now flag keychain items to require presence of a device passcode if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Use Encryption for  username and password and save in defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way: Don't.
The mobile phone is a very unsecure place to store information. If the security is #1 for you, you should not store sensitive information on the device.

You can use the default iOS security options, for example [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) with [CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html), or [openssl](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone), but your data never will be completely safe without a secure server component.

Keychain has it's very bad quality: It is as secure as the device's passcode.